# How to use path params in Grails 2.3.7

Tags: grails

I have a project using grails and I would like my controller url to look like

```
http://<domain>/<contextRoot>/<controller>/<method>/123
```

where 123 is the ID of an object. I can do this in Spring like...

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/path/to/{iconId}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
```

But since the annotations are handled by Grails I am not sure how to override them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

URL mappings are done within grails-app/conf/UrlMappings.groovy The [documentation](http://grails.org/doc/2.3.4/ref/Plug-ins/URL%20mappings.html) can explain in further details what you can do but for your example you can do the following:

```
class UrlMappings {
    static mappings = {
        "/path/to/${iconId}"(controller: 'myController', action: 'myAction')
        "/$controller/$action?/$id?"{
            constraints {
                // apply constraints here
            }
        }

        "/"(view:"/index")
        "500"(view:'/error')
    }
}
```

Take note that the mappings are first match basis, so you are adding a static path to a controller and action. Your iconId will be exposed automatically in the parameters as `params.iconId`

Comment: Hummmm I am surprised grails still uses a mapping file. why isn't it using package scanning and annotations or some such thing. I would assume that is possible but clearly not in the convention.

Comment: Well, one of the main reasons for using UrlMappings class is because it can contain logic, modify the request, response, and such. While I can appreciate the spring annotations for controllers this offers more flexibility for complex customization.

Comment: I thought that type of thing was why we use filters (not berating just trying to understand). It seems like it is less self documenting to go looking. Will this be the convention for 3 as well?

Comment: You are right, there is a cross over in functionality with filters, but that's perhaps because of my examples given. As far as I know there isn't any plans to change how URL mappings are handled in 3.x. At least there hasn't been any discussion of it on the dev or user mailing lists. Typically people don't change URL mappings unless they have a specific use case. 95% of the mappings are by convention and caught by the "/$controller/$action?/$id?" mapping.

Answer (score 1):

Add the following to `UrlMappings.groovy`

```
"/$controller/$action?/$id?"
```